# Foreign key SQL query not working

Tags: mysql, sql, foreign-keys

I have a table called `user-friend` having `UID and FID.`
I have another table called `user-friend-type` , It has UID and FID as `Foreign key` with `CASCADE`,in that table  `ID, UID, FID` forms the Primary Key
The problem is that if I issue statement
`delete from User-friend where UID=1 and FID=2`. it also deleted all the UID=1 from `User-Friend-type` and that is very strange for me. am I missing something?

here is SHOW Create for user-friend-type

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `userfrnd_source` (
  `id` int(16) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `userId` int(16) NOT NULL,
  `friendId` int(16) NOT NULL,
  `source_import_Id` int(16) NOT NULL,
  `sourceType` varchar(56) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`,`userId`,`friendId`),
  KEY `friendId` (`friendId`),
  KEY `source_import_Id` (`source_import_Id`),
  KEY `ufsource_ufdfk_idx` (`userId`,`friendId`)
)
```

SHOW CREATE for user-friend (Parent)

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `user_friend_detail` (
  `id` int(8) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `userId` int(16) NOT NULL,
  `friendId` int(16) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`,`userId`,`friendId`),
  KEY `ufd_users_fk1_idx` (`userId`),
  KEY `ufd_usersfk2_idx` (`friendId`)
)

ALTER TABLE `userfrnd_source`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `userfrnd_source_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`friendId`) REFERENCES `user_friend_detail` (`friendId`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  ADD CONSTRAINT `userfrnd_source_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`userId`) REFERENCES `user_friend_detail` (`userId`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE;

--
-- Constraints for table `user_friend_detail`
--
ALTER TABLE `user_friend_detail`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `ufd_usersfk1` FOREIGN KEY (`userId`) REFERENCES `users` (`userId`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  ADD CONSTRAINT `ufd_usersfk2` FOREIGN KEY (`friendId`) REFERENCES `users` (`userId`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE;
```

The engine is `InnoDB`

Comment: What does `SHOW CREATE TABLE` look like for both tables?

Comment: Read documentation carefully: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-foreign-key-constraints.html, find description of `ON DELETE CASCADE` and how it works.

Comment: +1 to suggestion from @ExplosionPills. It's hard to visualize what you're talking about with all the columns and references. It's easy to  use `SHOW CREATE TABLE \`User-friend\`` and also for the other table, then edit your question and paste the output.

Comment: @ExplosionPills added the table

Comment: @BillKarwin added the table

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for adding the DDL, it's now more clear to see what's happening.

You're defining the foreign keys in an unconventional way.

A "detail" table would typically be the child table, the one with the foreign keys, and it referencing the "type" table which would be the parent. So you appear to have these foreign keys backwards.
**edit:** this turns out to be my confusion, just because "detail" is often associated with child tables.

Also, FK's should reference only the columns in the PRIMARY KEY or non-null UNIQUE KEY in the parent table.  You instead had a separate FK for each of UID and FID, referencing non-unique secondary indexes in the parent table. InnoDB is quite unusual in that it allows you to define foreign keys referencing non-unique indexes, but this is nonstandard for SQL and it can cause very confusing results.

Also, each of your tables has its own auto-increment id. This is fine, but it means that the child table won't have the correct id values to reference its parent table. To solve this, you can define a UNIQUE KEY for the foreign key to reference, without the auto-increment column.

And be sure to use multi-column foreign keys to match the multi-column unique key it references, do not make two single-column foreign keys, because that will behave differently.

So I would recommend the following DDL instead:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `userfrnd_source` (
  `id` int(16) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `userId` int(16) NOT NULL,
  `friendId` int(16) NOT NULL,
  `source_import_Id` int(16) NOT NULL,
  `sourceType` varchar(56) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`,`userId`,`friendId`),
  KEY `friendId` (`friendId`),
  KEY `source_import_Id` (`source_import_Id`),
  KEY `ufsource_ufdfk_idx` (`userId`,`friendId`)
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `user_friend_detail` (
  `id` int(8) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `userId` int(16) NOT NULL,
  `friendId` int(16) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`,`userId`,`friendId`),
  UNIQUE KEY `ufd_users_fk1_idx` (`userId`, `friendId`),
  KEY `ufd_usersfk2_idx` (`friendId`)
);

-- change to a single FK constraint, with two columns  
ALTER TABLE `userfrnd_source`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `userfrnd_source_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`userId`,`friendId`) 
  REFERENCES `user_friend_detail` (`userId`,`friendId`) 
  ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE;
```

Comment: More than one row with the same values for both userId *and* friendId?

Comment: Yes more than one row

Comment: And is there more than one row in `user_friend_detail` for a given userid/friendid pair of values? Or could this be unique?

Comment: that would be unique, thats why I said, User_friend_detail is the parent table and other one is child table

Comment: Okay, then perhaps the direction of the reference is not at issue. I was thrown off by your terms of source and detail. I have edited the recommended DDL above.

Comment: it gives  #1005 - Can't create table, when I try to add the constraints to the usrfrnd_source table

Comment: I corrected a typo in the above DDL. It works on my system. If there's another problem please create a sqlfiddle and show exactly what statements you are running.